# Output of a PSD fed a square wave

Tags: modulation, phase, demodulation

This is the question given in one of my papers.

[image]

Input is a square wave, if phase shift was zero it would be just flat positive line, if phase is pi it would be flat negative line.

Here the phase change is pi/2 but it is not specified whether it is leading or lagging.
I am guessing the output is either a a rising or falling triangle wave, but I do not know how to prove it by calculation or drawing it out.

Comment: Hint: it's likely that the demodulator is an EXOR gate.

Comment: No clue how that hint is meant to help me. I think its just going to be zero, its halfway transition between +1 and -1 level. Would explain why lead/lag doesn't matter. I suppose maybe 45deg shift is a triangle ramp.